# Symfony permission recommendation: same user cli and webserver

Tags: apache, symfony

I read this recommendation in the [installation guidelines](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup) from Symfony:

> **1. Use the same user for the CLI and the web server**
>
> In development environments, it is a common practice to use the same UNIX user for the CLI and the web server because it avoids any of these permissions issues when setting up new projects. This can be done by editing your web server configuration (e.g. commonly httpd.conf or apache2.conf for Apache) and setting its user to be the same as your CLI user (e.g. for Apache, update the User and Group values).

This is only good practice for local development environments or should I do this on my public test & prod server as well? To me this doesn't seem as a very secure configuration?

**Questions** Can I safely follow this recommendation on a prod server? What are the risks, if there are any?

Comment: personally I dont do it in dev either... its not hard to set-up permissions properly and its good practice when you have to do it on production/test. But I guess its personal preference in dev, but Id not do it on production/test.

Comment: I never did it either, I was wondering if it would be safer or not. And what kind of risks you could have doing this on a prod. environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recommendation give an easy alternative to avoid the common permissions problem.

I would prefer setup the web server permissions correctly once and keep the default webserver group/user.

[The documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup) has a good guide to achieve this.

**EDIT**

You shouldn't make your CLI user as your webserver user, especially in production because it opens you up to all kinds of potential abuse.

The whole point of the `www-data` user is that it is an unprivileged user, by default not able to write to any file .

Your CLI user is most often `root`, also keep the `www-data` user as the web server owner protect you from bad manipulations that can involves a lot of problems and potential security issues.

Plus, if your webserver is under an attack, other services which depends on the same user can be also compromised.

Server daemons accessible from the outside network (such as the web server) typically run as an unprivileged user so that in the event that they are hacked due to a vulnerability, the possible things the attacker can do is minimal.

Comment: That's not really an answer to my question. And the documentation you provide is the same link as I gave in my question. I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: I've updated my answer for more precisions and really answer your question.